# dict to json over loop python

Tags: python, json

I'm using Twitter's streaming api to extract tweets using Tweepy and write them to a json file. So far, i've extracted the tweets successfully and wrote them to a json file using `file write` but when i try to use `json package` i get error as mentioned in the code below.

```
 def on_data(self, data):
    #to convert data to dict format since twitter data is in string format
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    try:
        with open('twitter_data.json','ab') as f:
                if 'limit' in json_data.keys():
                    return True
                else:
                    #This method works
                    #f.write(json.dumps(json_data)+ "\n")
                    #this one does not as it concatenates dict i.e different dict are not separated by a comma
                    json.dump(json_data,f)
                    return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print e
        logging.debug('Error %s',e)
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the right data but don't have the line separator... so add it yourself

```
import json
with open('deleteme', 'a') as fp:
    json.dump('data', fp)
    fp.write('\n')
```